# Missing classes in PDFBox2.0

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am migrating an application (`PDF2SVG` at http://github.com/contentmine/pdf2svg) from `PDFBox-1.8.8` to `PDFBox-2.0.6`. In the POM I have

```
    <pdfbox.version>2.0.6</pdfbox.version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>${pdfbox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...

and no other PDFBox packages.

I get the following missing imports:

```
//import org.apache.pdfbox.encoding.DictionaryEncoding;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.encoding.Encoding;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDMatrix;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDGraphicsState;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColorState;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.text.PDTextState;
//import org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition;
```

I have tried to find tips in https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html but without success.

I would like to know if there are replacement packages or classes and any description of the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a shortcut in your IDE to fix these... in netbeans, it's CTRL-SHIFT-i. Anyway, here are the classes:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.encoding.DictionaryEncoding;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.encoding.Encoding;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.state.PDGraphicsState;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.state.PDTextState;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;
```

I can't find PDColorState. One would have to see what you want to do.